# Change jquery element into provided string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery element of `input type='file'`.

`$('#test').prop('files')[0];`

I'd like to change the #test to a string.

```
var all_data    = new FormData();
$('input[type="file"]').each(function(index) { 
    var i           = index+1;
    var input_name  = '#test'+i;
    var file_data   = $(input_name).prop('files')[0]; //I think error start here

    alert(file_data);

    all_data.append('file', file_data);
});
alert(all_data);
```

But, it's not working.

HTML in PHP script:

```
$jml = 3;
for($i=1;$i<=$jml;$i++){ 
   echo "<input type='file' name='test".$i."' id='test".$i."' 
}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Are you saying that you want to read the content of the chosen file?

Comment: My main objective is to append each `input type=file` objectFile into the form data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: But, It gives error when I change  the `#test` to `#test+i`

Comment: If they're in a `<form>` you can just use `new FormData([reference to your form here])`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Only the `input type='file'` should be in the form data

Comment: Could you add a sample of your HTML to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> </head> <body>
    <input type="file" />

    <script>
        var all_data = new FormData();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert();
            $('input[type="file"]').change(function (e) {
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                all_data.append('file', file);
            });
        });

    </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: jst do : console.log(file)